# How does one process and combine nested array items into a new structure based on requirements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, reduce

I'm trying to sum the indices of an array and save them into a new one.

I have included an example array below, as well as my first try to solve this:

```
var data = [
  ["29.01.2020", 40, 10],
  ["30.01.2020", 80, 100],
  ["31.01.2020", 90, 500],
  ["01.02.2020", 30, 205],
  ["02.02.2020", 10, 74],
  ["03.02.2020", 30, 120]
];
```

The results I'm trying to create are something like these (either an array or an object):

```
[['0120', 210, 610], ['0220', 70, 399]]

{
  "0120": {
    "abc": 210,
    "def": 610
  },
  "0220": {
    "abc": 70,
    "def": 399
  }
}
```

This is something I found and was playing around with, perhaps something that might work with a little editing:

```
var res = {};
data.forEach((item)=>{
  if(Object.keys(res).includes(item[0])){
    res[item[1]] += item[1];
  } else {
    res[item[0]] = item[1];
  }   
});
```

Shortening the first index of my data array should be possible by using substrings I guess? What I'm mainly struggling with is getting it to summarize the index.

Any ideas how I can get there?
Thanks in advance

Comment: there is some magic here you've not explained: what do you mean "summarize"? Where are the keys coming from in your resulting object?

Comment: In my opinion the purely object based data structure for a result is totally broken; in comparison to the first one, the entirely list based one makes more sense ... did the OP already think about a mix like ... `{"0120": [210, 610], "0220": [70, 399]}` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **array reduce** method. Split the date string by dot. Then make it a key(according to your requirement two digit from month and last two digit from year) and based on that key just count it. At last using **Object.values** output the array.

```js
const data = [
  ['29.01.2020', 40, 10],
  ['30.01.2020', 80, 100],
  ['31.01.2020', 90, 500],
  ['01.02.2020', 30, 205],
  ['02.02.2020', 10, 74],
  ['03.02.2020', 30, 120],
];

const ret = data.reduce((prev, c) => {
  const p = prev;
  const date = c[0].split('.');
  const key = `${date[1]}${date[2].slice(-2)}`;
  if (!p[key]) p[key] = [key, c[1], c[2]];
  else p[key] = [key, p[key][1] + c[1], p[key][2] + c[2]];
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(ret));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the key from the first element of each subarray using `String.split` function. Using `split` function, you can extract the month and year string and combine it to generate the `key` of each array.

And based on that key, using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can generate the content you want.

```js
const data = [
  ["29.01.2020", 40, 10],
  ["30.01.2020", 80, 100],
  ["31.01.2020", 90, 500],
  ["01.02.2020", 30, 205],
  ["02.02.2020", 10, 74],
  ["03.02.2020", 30, 120]
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const dateArr = cur[0].split('.');
  const key = dateArr[1] + dateArr[2].slice(-2);
  if (acc[key]) {
    acc[key].abc += cur[1];
    acc[key].def += cur[2];
  } else {
    acc[key] = {
      abc: cur[1],
      def: cur[2]
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```